# Getting jni segv_accer or segv_mapper error sometimes only

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have below C++ code, which is called by a webserver through JNI.

```
 static shared_ptr<multimap<string,SomeObject> > cacheMap;

  void Cache::refresh(multimap<string, SomeObject>  delta){

  shared_ptr<multimap<string, SomeObject> >  old_cache=atomic_exchange(&cacheMap,make_shared<multimap<string,SomeObject> >(delta));

        shared_ptr<multimap<string, SomeObject> > old_readMap=atomic_load(&old_cache);
        if(old_readMap){
                for(std::multimap<string, SomeObject>::iterator it = old_readMap->begin(); it != old_readMap->end(); it++){
                        it->second.getSomeObject()->~SomeObject();
                }
                old_readMap->clear();
        }
}


list<int>  Cache::get(string key1,const char* key2){

    SomeObject value;
    list<int> IDs;
    try{
        shared_ptr<multimap<string,SomeObject> > readMap=atomic_load(&cacheMap);
        pair<mapIterator,mapIterator> result=readMap->equal_range(key1);
        for(auto iterator=result.first; iterator!=result.second; iterator++){
             value=iterator->second;
             if(!(value.getSomeObject()->test(key2,strlen(key2)))){
                     IDs.push_front(value.getInternalID());
                 }
        }

    }
    catch(...){
        std::exception_ptr p = std::current_exception();
        std::clog <<(p ? p.__cxa_exception_type()->name() : "null") << " from Cache.cpp " << std::endl;
    }
        return IDs;
}
```

The cacheMap will be refreshed by a cronjob for every 5 minutes and the request threads keep accessing the cache through get(). This is a multithreaded environment. Everything works fine, after 3 or 4 days I get this SEGV_ACCER/ SEGV_MAPPER errors with the dump looking like below
(few lines from the dump)

```
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libstdc++.so.6+0xd7172]  std::string::assign(std::string const&)+0x12

...

Stack: [0x00007fed854c2000,0x00007fed855c3000],  sp=0x00007fed855c08b0,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libstdc++.so.6+0xd7172]  std::string::assign(std::string const&)+0x12
C  [libCustomCache.so+0x1c0b0]  Cache::get(std::string, char const*)+0x122
```

I have used `shared_ptr` and atomic operations for thread safety, but still getting this error. Any idea on how to debug this?

Comment: Most likely scenario: `Cache::get` and `Cache::refresh` started simultaneously, with refresh clearing out part of the map that `::get` needed. I presume you want `Cache::refresh` to be the one that clears out the map instead of `Cache::get`?

Comment: You could catch this condition inside `Cache::get` by looking at `old_readMap.use_count` and waiting for it to drop to 1 (=one reference).

Comment: @Botje Yes, I clear map only in refresh and lookup in get. Will try out your suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cache::refresh` and `Cache::get` race to destroy and read the same `SomeObject` object at the same time. It is a race condition.

An atomic pointer or atomic usage of `std::shared_ptr` here only make the value of the pointer atomic and race-free, but not the object the pointer refers to.

One robust approach would be to use C++17 [`std::shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) or C++14 [boost::shared_mutex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex) to allow readers concurrent access to the cache and exclusive access for writers only.

You should also remove the need to destroy `SomeObject` manually.

Example:

```
using namespace std;

namespace {

shared_mutex m;
multimap<string, SomeObject> cacheMap; // SomeObject doesn't need to be manually destroyed.

} // namespace 

void Cache::refresh(multimap<string, SomeObject> delta){
    std::unique_lock lock(m); // Writer exclusive lock.
    cacheMap = std::move(delta);
}

list<int> Cache::get(string const& key1, const char* key2) {
    list<int> IDs;
    std::shared_lock lock(m); // Readers shared lock.
    for(auto result = readMap->equal_range(key1); result.first != result.second; ++result.first) {
        auto&& value = *result.first;
        if(!(value.getSomeObject()->test(key2, strlen(key2))))
            IDs.push_front(value.getInternalID());
    }
    return IDs;
}
```

Comment: I could see you have changed the cacheMap to an instance from static, can't I retain it as static. Secondly, in my case, if I don't destroy the SomeObject manually it was not releasing the memory.  Will try this.

Comment: @Raj I put it into an unnamed namespace for you. Or use `static`.

Comment: I tried this solution; however, the memory of the previous Someobject is not released. Whenever refresh is called the memory keeps growing. Clearly showing previous object memory is not reclaimed. The Someobject holds memory allocated on heap it holds 30GB data.

Comment: @Raj You shouldn't need to call that destructor manually, it may cause leaks or multiple destructions. `SomeObject` should be changed to be a value/move-only/non-copyable type.